# Error converting data type varchar to bigint. Inline sql statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is the code i have used to get LocationID from database with MerchantID. I am getting an exception from Fill dataset part. Please help me out,. The error is Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

```
public DataSet getLocationID(long MerchantID)
{
    //long LOCID = null;
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@merchantID",MerchantID)
        };

        string strCommandText = "Select LocationID from Merchant_Location where MerchantID ='@merchantID' order by LocationID ASC";

        Debug.WriteLine(strCommandText);

        DataSet pds = new DataSet();

        SqlHelper.FillDataset(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.Text, strCommandText, pds, new string[] { "LocID" }, parameters);
        return pds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //LogError("Error Occurred When Retrieving LocationID: " + MerchantID.ToString(), ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the MerchantID field in the Merchant_Location table a varchar field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around `@merchantID` in your query text, assuming that MerchantID is a bigint.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the ticks.

Instead of `='@merchantID' order` use `=@merchantID order`